# Migrate code with R# Structural Search and Replace

Tags: c#, resharper-2019

I have legacy systems that I want to migrate to a new data model. It boils down to many type name changing. In order to not break existing code, I plan to use compiler switches:

```
#if NEW
    var variable = new MyNewType();
#else
    MyOldType variable = new MyOldType();
#endif
```

I created a Resharper replace pattern:

```
#if NEW
    var $variable$ = new $type$();
#else
    $type$ $variable$ = new $type$();
#endif
```

`type` is defined as a type placeholder and `variable` is an identifier placeholder. However, I get a syntax error while parsing that expression:

> unexpected placeholder "variable"

Is introducing compiler switches with Resharper not possible, or where did I go wrong?

Comment: You say "variable is defined as a type placeholder and variable is an identifier placeholder". Did you mean one of them is `type`, or both are `variable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, R# doesn't support this case. I believe it's because R# relies on the Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) of the **current** code. And in your case AST depends on which statements would actually be compiled based on whether `NEW` is defined or not.